# Isomorphism of finitely generated modules over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated

Review question from my first course on Algebraic Structures:

Let $M, N, P$ be finitely generated modules over a PID.

- a) Show that if $M⊕M≅N⊕N$, then $M≅N$.
- b) Show that if $M⊕P≅N⊕P$,    then $M≅N$.

---

My attempt so far (not finished):

a) We know, from the uniqueness of the theorem about elementary divisors, that $M$ and $N$ are isomorph if and only if they have the same rank and the same list of elementary divisors.

And that any finitely generated module over a PID $R$ can be expressed as

$R^r \oplus R/(p_1^{k_1}) \oplus R/(p_2^{k_2}) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(p_n^{k_n})$

where $p_1^{k_1},\ldots,p_n^{k_n}$ are prime powers in $R$.

Let $m,n$ denote the number of times $R/(p^k)$ appears as an elementary divisor of $M,N$ respectively.

Since $M⊕M≅N⊕N$,

$m+m=n+n$

and then $m=n$

The same argument can be made for the rank of $R^r$.

---

Am I correct so far? I understand that I still need to show that the list of elementary divisors is the same.

How would I go about doing that? I'm a bit lost after this point.

Comment: What are you not sure about?

Comment: Hey. Basically, I understand why the list of elementary divisors is the same but I'm not really sure how to write it down. A dumb analogy: if I have two identical shopping lists (M(+)M) and you went to buy the same items and made two lists as well (N(+)N), of course each of our lists are the same (M=N). I'm just finding it weird to put it to paper... Any tips?